# Variable number of ampersands in align/alignat env

Tags: equations, align, alignat

I am trying to display this equation in latex:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\forall \, z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad  & (2z + 1 - i)(i\bar{z}+i-2)=0\\
                               \iff & 2z + 1 - i = 0 \quad          &&\text{ or } i\bar{z}+i-2 = 0\\
                               \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{ or } \bar{z} = -i(-i+2)\\
                               \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{ or } z = 1 + 2i
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

As you can see the alignements are correct, however the `or`s are aligned with the end of the first line, whereas I want it aligned just after the `\quad` of second line. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, the right-hand side of the first line is aligned the way you want it,
and it doesn't have any additional alignment points, so you can simply ignore
its width.  `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` is very good for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\forall \, z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad  & \mathrlap{(2z + 1 - i)(i\bar{z}+i-2)=0}\\
                               \iff & 2z + 1 - i = 0 \quad          &&\text{ or } i\bar{z}+i-2 = 0\\
                               \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{ or } \bar{z} = -i(-i+2)\\
                               \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{ or } z = 1 + 2i
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

You can just add some negative space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\forall \, z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad
       & (2z + 1 - i)(i\bar{z}+i-2)=0\hidewidth\\
  \iff & 2z + 1 - i = 0 \quad          &&\text{or } i\bar{z}+i-2 = 0\\
  \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{or } \bar{z} = -i(-i+2)\\
  \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{or } z = 1 + 2i
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\hidewidth` is not really documented in the LaTeX manual, but it's a very handy tool in alignments; it is essentially

```
\hspace{-1000pt plus 1fill}
```

so a very large negative skip, but with infinite stretchability. Thus the cell with `\hidewidth` will never be the widest one, but it will be filled up correctly nonetheless.

I suggest using `\quad` also after “or”, for symmetry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\forall \, z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad
       & (2z + 1 - i)(i\bar{z}+i-2)=0\hidewidth\\
  \iff & 2z + 1 - i = 0 \quad          &&\text{or}\quad i\bar{z}+i-2 = 0\\
  \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{or}\quad \bar{z} = -i(-i+2)\\
  \iff & z = -\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}2i   &&\text{or}\quad z = 1 + 2i
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]